# ERROR O PROBLEMAS EN SUBSCRIBE PERDIDA DE DATOS HATEOAS O HAL

Tags: angular11

**Aqui dejo mi codigo**

```
export interface UsuariosHateoas{
    _embedded: {
        usuarios: Usuario[];
        _links: { self: { href: string } };
    }
}
   export interface Usuario {
        userId?: number;
        userName?: string;
        userPassword?: string;
        userEnabled?: boolean;
        name?: string;
        lastName?: string;
        userEmail?: string;
        roles?: any[];
    }
```

*La conexión al backend**

```
  getUsers() {//: Observable<Usuario[]>
    return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.urlEndpoint)
      .pipe(map((response: any)=>{ return response._embedded.usuarios}));
  }
```

**tengo un problema al intentar retorna datos de tipo JSON en si son datos HATEOAS o HAL quien pertenece a lo datos HATEOAS este dato
me retorna con links talvez ahí sea el problema pero no se como
obviarlas o utilizarlas se pierde pareciera que no lo asigna, pero si
lo  estoy asignando imprimo los datos dentro del susbcribe y existe
tal como se ve en la imagen pero al retornar se pierde y me imprime
vacío**

```
    import { UserFormService } from 'src/app/auth/forms/user-form.service';
    import { Usuario } from './../../core/models/usuario';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService } from 'src/app/core/services/user.service';

    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserControllerService {
      private usuario: Usuario = {};
      public userData:Usuario[]=[];
        constructor(private userFormService: UserFormService, private userService: UserService) {}
    
    
      }
      getUsers():Usuario[]{
        //DATO SE PIERDE AL RETORNAR 
         this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
           response=>{
    
             this.userData=response;
             console.log(this.userData);//Data existe
            }
         );
         return  this.userData;// Retorno vacio
      }
    
    }
```

**dato imprimido retornado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**dato imprimido antes de retornar**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Como recomendación, las mayúsculas sostenidas son completamente innecesarias. Te vamos a leer sin necesidad de gritos :P

Comment: @Alfabravo ok gracias por la recomendación

Comment: los datos no se pierden.. tenes una promesa y un console log fuera de la promesa...